# What are the topics that must be covered in a beginning graph theory course?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, soft-question

Good day to everyone.

It will be my first time to make a syllabus on elementary graph theory. My question will be:

What are the topics that must be covered in a beginning graph theory course? Also can you help me find a great book on beginning graph theory?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's a mathematics educators SE site.

Comment: If that's not "primarily opinion-based" I don't know what is...

Comment: For the books, you might have a look at older questions tagged [graph-theory+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory+book-recommendation) or [graph-theory+reference-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory+reference-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many books for graph theory, and you should select the topics that suit the education goals of the course. For example, in computer science the Graph theory algorithms is highly considered as main topic in each graph theory course. 
Personally, I prefer the following two books:

- [Introduction to Graph Theory](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/igt/)
- [Graph Theory (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849966907)